# How can I prevent states from resetting after a http request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

when I send the server an HTTP request ( patch request in the checkbox onChange function) and update the state other states will be deleted until I reload the page and they will be back
so how can I update the states without losing the others?
I'm not totally sure but I think the problem is where I'm updating the state with the response I get from the server I think I'm not updating the state and I'm just adding the new response to it and replacing the others

here's my code

```
const Form = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([]);

  const debounce = (func, timeout = 350) => {
    let timer;
    return (...args) => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        func.apply(this, args);
      }, timeout);
    };
  };
  const saveInput = (e, id) => {
    const x = !e.target.checked;
    console.log(x);

    axios
      .patch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/todo/todos/${id}/`, {
        completed: x,
      })
      .then(
        (response) => {
          console.log(response.data);

          setTodos([response.data]);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  };
  const processChange = debounce((e, id) => saveInput(e, id));

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/todo/todos/").then((response) => {
      setTodos(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <form>
      <h1>Todo list</h1>
      <button>Add</button>
      <div>
       
          {todos.map((todo) => (
            <ul key={todo.id}>
              <li>{todo.title}</li>
              <li>{todo.description}</li>
              <button onClick={() => deleteHandler(todo.id)}>delete</button>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                placeholder="completed"
                onChange={(e) => processChange(e, todo.id)}
                checked={todo.completed}
              />
            </ul>
          ))}
       
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Comment: Can you please specify which "other states" will be deleted?

Comment: I have useEffect which renders after each page reload to get the data from the server and I set the data in the states and render them out 
e.g: I have 3 todos when i update 1 those 2 will be removed from states

Comment: While updating state value using previous value, use the callback argument. See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
const saveInput = (e, id) => {
const x = !e.target.checked;
console.log(x);
const newTodos = [...todos];
const filteredTodos = newTodos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id);
axios
  .patch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/todo/todos/${id}/`, {
    completed: x,
  })
  .then(
    (response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      filteredTodos.push(response.data);
      setTodos(filteredTodos);
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
```

};

Comment: I tried this but it gave me this error: Encountered two children with the same key
I'm in my map method I'm giving the children the key={todo.id} property 
and each item has a unique id as I add them in the back-end 
so the problem is it creates a new item with the same id instead of updating it

Comment: oh Sorry my Wrong !! the filter method returns new array of elements . 
Try it .
const filteredTodos = newTodos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id);
 filteredTodos .push(response.data);
 setTodos(filteredTodos );

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `saveInput` function you are resetting your `todos` with the new response data. Thus you are losing the data from your component initialization. What you need to do is to destructure your existing data and add them with your new payload.

You can either do this:

```
setTodos([...todos, response.data]);
```

Or this:

```
setTodos((prevState) => ([...prevState, response.data]))
```

The second option is the best practice as this returns your state correctly.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this but it gave me this error: Encountered two children with the same key
I'm in my map method I'm giving the children the key={todo.id} property 
and each item has a unique id as I add them in the back-end 
so the problem is it creates a new item with the same id instead of updating it

Comment: Share your payload example. Like whats inside todos and inside response.data

Answer (score 0):

So Morteza's answer worked but it had a tiny problem which was when i updated the state the order of the state ( array ) would change because of `.push()` method which pushes the item to the last index
here is the solution which works fine and won't change the orders:

```js
setTodos(val => val.map(item => item.id === response.data.id ? (response.data) : item));
```

It's getting the **todos** current state, mapping and checking if each of its `item.id` is equal to the `item.id` from the server and if it is, then replaced and updated with a **response.data**, if not then nothing changes.